# Redirect catching the internal domain

Tags: apache

So I have this rule set up:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.clientdomain.com$

RewriteRule ^file/path/file.pdf$  https://www.newdomain.com/file/path/file.pdf [NC,R=301,L]

And for some reason unknown to me this rule(and all like this one for PDF files) somehow catches the internal.clientdomain.com also. I would like for it to stop doing that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed.
Took some configs from another file and placed them in the file with the redirects. Everything is working now.